# When WKExtension.scheduleBackgroundRefresh is supposed to call scheduledCompletion handler?

Tags: swift3, watchos-3, wkrefreshbackgroundtask

I'm trying to schedule background task with such line:

```
WKExtension.shared().scheduleBackgroundRefresh(withPreferredDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(5) * 60), userInfo: nil, scheduledCompletion: self.scheduledCompletion)
```

where

```
func scheduledCompletion(error: Error?) {
        if error == nil { print("successfully scheduled application background refresh") }
        else { print("error scheduling background refresh, error: \(error)") }
}
```

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkextension/1650848-schedulebackgroundrefresh):

> `scheduledCompletion` A block that is called by the system after the
>   background app refresh task has completed.

But by unknown reason it is being called straightly after background refresh task is being *scheduled*. Background refresh task is being called on correct time, tho, and `scheduledCompletion` is not being called after that.

So is it an error in documentation, bug in WatchKit or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Despite documentation's description, `scheduledCompletion` will be when the task will be scheduled. It was mentioned during WWDC16 [Keeping Your Watch App Up to Date](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/218/) session at 11:23:

[image]