# Can't get Apple Watch complication to update in WatchOS 3

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-3, clockkit

I can't get the Apple Watch Complication to update/refresh in WatchOS 3. I I'm using the following code in my `ComplicationController.swift` file.

```
func getSupportedTimeTravelDirections(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimeTravelDirections) -> Void) {
    handler([.forward])
}

func getTimelineStartDate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (Date?) -> Void) {
    handler(Date())
}

func getTimelineEndDate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (Date?) -> Void) {
    handler(Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60 * 30))
}
```

I have also tried to schedule an update from the handle background task method in the `ExtensionDelegate.swift` but it dosen't seem to work either.

```
func scheduleNextRefresh() {
    let fireDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 30 * 60)
    let userInfo = ["lastActiveDate" : Date(),
                    "reason" : "updateWeekNumber"] as Dictionary

    WKExtension.shared().scheduleBackgroundRefresh(withPreferredDate: fireDate, userInfo: userInfo as NSSecureCoding) { (error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("Succesfully updated week number")
        }
    }
}

func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
    for task: WKRefreshBackgroundTask in backgroundTasks {
        if WKExtension.shared().applicationState == .background {
            if task is WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask {
                print("Task received")
                scheduleNextRefresh()
            }
        }
        task.setTaskCompleted()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WKRefreshBackgroundTask` do not update anything itself, it just allows your app to go to active state and run code (placed somewhere around `print("Task received")` line) that will update your complication. Remember that number of `WKRefreshBackgroundTask`s is limited.

Complication can be updated such way:

```
let server = CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()

// if you want to add new entries to the end of timeline
server.activeComplications?.forEach(server.extendTimeline)

// if you want to reload all the timeline, which according to snippets looks like your case
server.activeComplications?.forEach(server.reloadTimeline)
```

This will cause system to call `getCurrentTimelineEntry(for:withHandler:)` methods of your `CLKComplicationDataSource`, where you can prepare and return updated entries.

More about complications update [in documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ManagingComplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH28-SW1). More about background tasks [in WWDC16 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/218/).

Comment: Thanks! Where is the best place to call the ```scheduleNextRefresh()``` method? I have done it in the interface controller for the watch app in the awake method.

Comment: generally, you want to update complication when new data arrives, so that place is a good candidate to call schedule background task from. But pay attention that completion handler of `scheduleBackgroundRefresh` is called when background refresh is *scheduled*, not executed, documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextension/1650848-schedulebackgroundrefresh has an error. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238434/when-wkextension-schedulebackgroundrefresh-is-supposed-to-call-scheduledcompleti

Comment: This doesn't work for me - nothing changes and `getCurrentTimelineEntry(for:withHandler:)` won't get called